# How do I listen to the client using the Java Socket?

Tags: java, rest, sockets, web-services, serversocket

I'm working with "ServerSocket" and "Socket", the problem I'm going through is this: I create a server using serverSocket, I'm waiting for the client to connect, when it connects I'll receive some information, and here's my question, how do I keep listening to the client and receive instructions from it?

In the example below I am creating a server, when the client connects I save the connection within the "clientSocket ".

```
@GET
@Path("/createServer")
public String conect() throws IOException { 
    
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3242);      
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    ...
    ...
  }
```

From this point I need to always listen to this clientSocket, when the client send some information I need to capture to perform some actions, how to do that?

Comment: You read from the socket's input stream, and write any response to its output stream. This is rather basic. See the Custom Networking section of the Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

`ServerSocket.accept()` gives you a `java.net.Socket`. Doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)

From there on, you can read on that socket using its input stream (`Socket.getInputStream()`) or write to its output stream (`Socket.getOutputStream()`)

Your sockets (client and server) will live until they're `close`d, or garbage collected, so remember to keep a strong reference to each one as long as you need them.

Sample programs (simple echo server. Type `bye` in client to exit):

**Server.java**

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Server {

  private static volatile boolean stopped = false;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3001)) {
      System.out.println("Server ready to accept connections on port " + server.getLocalPort());

      final Socket client = server.accept();
      System.out.println("Client connected using remote port " + client.getPort());

      final Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
          try (InputStream clientIn = client.getInputStream()) {
            try (OutputStream clientOut = client.getOutputStream()) {
              echo(clientIn, clientOut);
            }
          }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
          ioe.printStackTrace();
          stopped = true;
        }
      });
      t.setDaemon(true);
      t.start();

      while (!stopped) {
        Thread.sleep(10);
      }
      System.out.println("Program exit");

    }

  }

  private static void echo(InputStream clientIn, OutputStream clientOut) throws IOException {
    
    try (Scanner clientScan = new Scanner(clientIn, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
      try (OutputStreamWriter clientWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(clientOut, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        
        while (!stopped) {
          final String fromClient = clientScan.nextLine();
          System.out.println("In: " + fromClient);
          clientWriter.write(fromClient);
          clientWriter.write(System.lineSeparator());
          clientWriter.flush();
          if ("bye".equalsIgnoreCase(fromClient.trim())) {
            stopped = true;
          }
        }
        System.out.println("Loop done");
        
      }
    }
    
  }

}
```

**Client.java**

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
  private static volatile boolean stopped = false;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Client launched");
    try (Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 3001)) {
      System.out.println("Connected on remote port " + client.getPort() + " from " + client.getLocalPort());

      try (Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        try (OutputStreamWriter toServer = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream())) {

          final Thread t = new Thread(() -> printEverything(client));
          t.setDaemon(true);
          t.start();

          while (!stopped) {
            final String fromConsole = console.nextLine();
            if (stopped)
              break;
            toServer.write(fromConsole);
            toServer.write(System.lineSeparator());
            toServer.flush();
          }

        }
      }

    }
    System.out.println("Program exit");

  }

  private static void printEverything(Socket client) {
    try (Scanner server = new Scanner(client.getInputStream())) {
      while (!stopped) {
        final String fromServer = server.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Server said: " + fromServer);
        if ("bye".equalsIgnoreCase(fromServer.trim())) {
          stopped = true;
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Loop done. Press enter to exit");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      stopped = true;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much! :)

Comment: no suitable constructor found for Scanner(InputStream,Charset)